# Random 0 being inserted in to encoded array query params in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, parameters

We have some checkboxes -- super normal and generic, with a name of `whatever_value[]` as made by rails, to pass a collection of selected checkboxes for our search form. Works 99.99% of the time. However, on random occasion we get some failures because we're getting requests at:

```
https://our.url/?whatever_value%5B0%5D=21
```

Note the `0` in between the `%5B` and the `%5D` (url encoded opening and closing brackets, `[` `]`). In the other 99.99% of cases, it shows up as:

```
https://our.url/?whatever_value%5B%5D=21
```

The difference is causing rails to interpret the value as a hash (`{"whatever_value" => {"0" => "21"}}` instead of an array `{"whatever_value" => [21]}`)

I've noticed this at past places I've worked as well, and I have a feeling that there might be a browser that is rendering checkboxes oddly or sending the checked params oddly, but I have been unable to figure out what is going on.

Comment: That is odd. A simple hook could ensure that `params[:whatever_value]`'s value is an array, but I understand you should not have to do this. Is this issue related to the browser? (chrome/firefox/opera/IE/others ?)

Comment: Yeah -- I'm probably going to code a little check, but I'm curious as to the root cause. 

The users agent string was: `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.101 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: Awesome find!  Very interested if this is a bug in the form builder or the request generation

Comment: Do you know when 0 appears?

Comment: It's completely random -- happens only about once every couple weeks/month.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that this error may appears when you try to use facebook "share" button.   Because I have such issue and I don't know how to fix it yet. "shareable" gem generates such erroneous url.